# Displaying rolls from MySQLi skiping one roll

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im looking to display rolls from a MySQLi but I would like to display one yes and one no... example

If I use this code:

```
$sqldisplay = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `albums` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($rowdisplay = $sqldisplay->fetch_assoc()) {

echo $rowdisplay['id'].'<br>';

}
```

It will display

```
10
9
8
7
6
```

But im looking to display it like this:

```
10
8
6
4
2
```

Is it posible? And if so, how can it be done?

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Do you mean that you just want even numbers, and not odd ones?

Comment: I thought of that, but if I add a new row, then it would have to change the code to make it the other way around :(

Comment: Do you want to select odd numbers if the highest ID is odd, and even numbers if the highest ID is even?

Answer (score 1):

To display alternating rows, first double your limit.

```
$sqldisplay = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `albums` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Then use a boolean switch to determine whether each row will be displayed.

```
$display = true;

while ($rowdisplay = $sqldisplay->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($display) echo $rowdisplay['id'].'<br>';

    $display = !$display;   // switch the display on/off

}
```

This way, you won't have to depend on the value of the ID, something that could produce unexpected results if any IDs are missing due to deleted rows, etc. A numeric ID is a surrogate key which should have no meaning other than uniquely identifying a row.

Answer (score 1):

Using `WHERE (id % 2) = 0` would give you only even numbers, and using `WHERE (id % 2) > 0` would get you odd numbers.

You can use this along with a subquery that selects `MAX(id)` and returns either `1` (for odd) or `0` (for even). This will ensure that if the id is even, just even IDs will be returned, and vice-versa, when applied with the logic explained in the paragraph above.

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `albums` 
GROUP BY `id` 
HAVING `id` % 2 = (CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `albums`) % 2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

With Paul's comment below, it's been pointed out that you can clean up the query even more, just doing `WHERE id % 2 = (SELECT MAX(id) % 2 FROM albums)` instead - this way you shouldn't need any `GROUP BY..HAVING`.

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `albums` 
WHERE id % 2 = (SELECT MAX(id) % 2 FROM albums)
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

You can also achieve this in PHP if you wish retrieve both datasets, see Don't Panic's answer for that (although I prefer to do it in MySQL if possible).

- [MySQL modulus `%` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod)

Comment: `WHERE id % 2 = (SELECT MAX(id) % 2 FROM albums)` should also work. No need for GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: Indeed. that's true - didn't even think of that (simplicity at its best, eh?). I was playing around with the query, and had aggregate function `MAX()` directly in the condition before, which is why it was grouped (with then having the condition in `HAVING`). Your approach is way cleaner, I'll edit it in. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just check if the modulo of the ID is 0 (no remainders) to return even numbers.

If you want to return odd numbers, change the modulo to equal 1.

If you want to select odd or even numbers depending on user input, you can easily make an if statement and use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to input the requested number (1 for odd ID rows to be returned, 0 for even rows).

```
SELECT `id` FROM `albums` WHERE `id` % 2 = 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

So your code will be:

```
$sqldisplay = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `albums` WHERE `id` % 2 = 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($rowdisplay = $sqldisplay->fetch_assoc()) 
{    
echo $rowdisplay['id'].'<br>';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you set id for order by.your result is According to insert each column

you must add column in you table for this .for example you can have column **orderBy** and you can specify the order of each display column
and then your query same

```
$sqldisplay = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `albums` ORDER BY `orderBy` DESC LIMIT 5");
```